# Relation among the dead time, recovery time and resolving time of a GM counter

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, experimental-technology

I have been researching a lot for my assignment about the relation among the dead time, recovery time and resolving time of a GM counter. Most of the articles I came across have varying definitions on each of them. Some articles don't distinguish between dead time and resolving time, and some others do. All the articles I came across simply gave the relation between dead time and resolving time in terms of counting rates. But they lack mathematical expressions for recovery time. Hence, to be specific, I am looking for any mathematical relation among these quantities and how to derive them if there is any. Thank you.

Comment: [Accurate Determination of the Deadtime and Recovery Characteristics of Geig er-Muller Counters](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/42/jresv42n3p241_A1b.pdf) includes a nice graph.